# PHP - Handle POST Form using select options as array

Tags: php, arrays, forms

I have the following form which has 3 dropdown boxes, one for each extra and each one has a different 'amount' that can be selected (i.e. 0-1, 0-2, 0-3). The select name is the same for each select, but i have passed the id of each into it to create an array.

I am now stuck in how i can get the results from the posted form?

I need to be able to tell which extras have been chosen with a value of more than 0. So i need to be able to tell how many of extra[1] has been chosen, how many of extra[2] and so on...

```
<form action="xxx.php" method="post">
<table width="100%">
<tr>
    <td>
        Option 1
    </td>
    <td>
        &pound;9.99
    </td>
    <td>
        <select name="extra[1]"><option value="0">0</option><option value="1">1</option><option value="2">2</option></select>
    </td>
</tr>

<tr>
    <td>
        Option 2
    </td>
    <td>
        &pound;14.99
    </td>
    <td>
        <select name="extra[2]"><option value="0">0</option><option value="1">1</option></select>
    </td>
</tr>

<tr>
    <td>
        Option 3
    </td>
    <td>
        &pound;24.99
    </td>
    <td>
        <select name="extra[3]"><option value="0">0</option><option value="1">1</option><option value="2">2</option><option value="3">3</option></select>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Have you looked at `print_r($_POST)`? You should have an array in `$_POST['extra']` which you can loop over like any other array.

Answer (score 0):

Bit rusty with direct access (used to Symfony), should be able to reference the values like this (after form submission):

```
// xxx.php

// Could use $_POST if you want, but I've always used $_REQUEST
$extras = $_REQUEST['extra'];

$extra1 = $extras[1];
$extra2 = $extras[2];
$extra3 = $extras[3];
```